# Find CPU L3 Cache Size using Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cpu

How can the L3 cache size of a CPU be found using Python running on a Windows system?

Tried [`py-cpuinfo`](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo) but it only outputs the L2 cache info, not L3.

```
import cpuinfo

print cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()
```

**Output**

```
{'count': 12, 'l2_cache_line_size': 6L, 'hz_advertised': '3.5000 GHz', 'bits': 64, 'brand': u'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5930K CPU @ 3.50GHz', 'vendor_id': u'GenuineIntel', 'cpuinfo_version': (3
, 3, 0), 'flags': ['3dnow', 'acpi', 'clflush', 'cmov', 'de', 'dts', 'fxsr', 'ia64', 'mca', 'mce', 'mmx', 'msr', 'mtrr', 'pse', 'sep', 'serial', 'ss', 'sse', 'sse2', 'tm', 'tsc'], 'raw_arch
_string': 'AMD64', 'l2_cache_size': 64L, 'l2_cache_associativity': '0x100L', 'hz_actual_raw': (3500000000L, 0), 'hz_actual': '3.5000 GHz', 'arch': 'X86_64', 'hz_advertised_raw': (350000000
0L, 0)}
```

Comment: I took a look at the source code for `py-cpuinfo`, and it appears the author gets L2 cache info himself [by running assembly instructions using `ctypes`](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo/blob/master/cpuinfo/cpuinfo.py#L965). Might be worth investing adding L3 cache retrieval as a patch to `py-cpuinfo`, building on top of its nifty classes?

Comment: I have filed a feature request for L3 cache sizes on [`py-cpuinfo`](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo/issues/76). In the meantime, launching `wmic cpu get L3CacheSize` in a separate process and reading the result should work well on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows specifically,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('wmic cpu get L3CacheSize')
```

is sufficient to retrieve information about the L3 cache size.

Comment: Great solution, however running it gave me the error `wmic get cpu L3CacheSize` on Windows 10

Comment: Is it possible to include the `wmic` binary with the script, then let the script run the included copy of `wmic` instead of using the one that came with the system's Window installation? Is there a `wmic` version that works with older Windows installation as well, like Windows XP, 7, 8, 10.

Comment: `wmic cpu get L3CacheSize` returned `0` for the cache size on a AMD A8-6800K... Thats strange

Comment: @Nyxynyx That's because the AMD A8-6800K [has no L3 cache](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/444/AMD_A8-Series_A8-6600K_vs_Intel_Core_i7_i7-6800K.html#specs). In Windows 10, [`wmic` has been renamed to `wbem`](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uwOhyUOPBKYJ:https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/5056wf/wmic_windows_10_not_working/+&cd=15&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). Unfortunately, I believe `wmic` is packaged with Windows and is not distributable - thus this solution does not work for every possible version of Windows. Perks of closed-source software! :D